# Call javascript in aspx.cs with div<%# Eval("variable") %>' as parameter in aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a collapsible and expandable gridview. When i change the dropdown in my gridview the gridview collapses due to the autopostback that is caused. I need to do a autopostback since I want to populate a second dropdown based on the first dropdown. Is there a way I can expanded it after it is collapsed. I am thinking of calling the javascript but i dont now how to call it since I have little knowledge in javascript. Thank you for your help.

Here is my javascript.

```
function divexpandcollapse(divname) {

    var div = document.getElementById(divname);

    var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);

    if (div.style.display == "none") {

        div.style.display = "inline";

        img.src = "../images/minus.gif";
    } else {

        div.style.display = "none";

        img.src = "../images/plus.gif";
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my indexChanged how can I add the javascript to expand the grid.

```
    protected void OnClosetIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Call javascript to reopen gridview
    }
```

And here is my front end

```
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("componente_id") %>');" >
                            <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("componente_id") %>" width="9px" border="0" src="../images/plus.gif"
                                alt="" /></a>   
                              <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/select.png" runat="server" CommandName="Select" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound"  Width="10px" Height="10px"/>                    
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20px" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Purchase Order ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblPurchaseOrderID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "componente_id") %>'  ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>   

       <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                       <td colspan="100%" style="background:#F5F5F5" >
                         <div id="div<%# Eval("componente_id") %>"  style="overflow:auto; display:none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                    <div class="header">
                        Cambiar la cantidad
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="validationOfTypeID">Armario:</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drCloset2" runat="server" Width="40%" Height="30px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "OnClosetIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="validationOfTypeID">cajón:</label>
                          <asp:DropDownList ID = "drDrawer2" runat="server" Width="40%" Height="30px" >
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                        <br />
                       <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                           <asp:DropDownList Height="30px" ID="drOperation" runat="server">
                               <asp:ListItem>+</asp:ListItem>
                               <asp:ListItem>-</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList> 
                        <asp:TextBox width="50px" ID="txtChangeQuantity" runat="server" TextMode="Number" min="0" step="1" Value="0"></asp:TextBox>
                                                          <br/>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnChangeQuantity" runat="server" Text="Validar" OnClick="change_quantity_Click" /> 
                        <asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Anular" AutoPostBack="True"  />
                    </div>
                             <asp:DetailsView id="DetailsView1" DataKeyNames="componente_id" Runat="server" Width="300px" Font-Names="Calibri"/>                              
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>



        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is a image of what it looks like :
[image: Table with drop down in expand]

Comment: "I need to do a autopostback since I want to populate a second dropdown based on the first dropdown" ...unless you use AJAX, of course

Comment: Yes, that would also solve my problem. How can I use ajax to prevent a autopostback and be able to still populate the second dropdown based on the first dropdown. Also I am so happy you are the first person to respond to my question thank you thank you so much.

Comment: remove the autopostback setting, handle the "change" event of the first dropdown using JavaScript, fire off an AJAX request which sends the server the currently selected value in the first dropdown as a parameter, and make the server send back a list of options to put into the second dropdown. Then when the ajax returns, use JavaScript to clear out the options in the second dropdown and re-populate them with the values returned by the AJAX call. This is called a "cascading dropdown" pattern and you can google lots of examples of it (google "cascading dropdown ajax asp.net" or similar terms)

Comment: Having said all that, I can't actually see any dropdown lists in your code?

Comment: Yes I will add it to the question